# URI Matching on content provider not matching correctly

Tags: android, pattern-matching, uri, android-contentprovider

I've been trying now for a while but I can't seem to resolve my URI matching problem. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Here is my declaration of the content uri and the uri matcher:

```
private static final String AUTHORITY = "edu.uprm.civil.db";

public static final Uri CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + AUTHORITY);

private static UriMatcher sURIMatcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
static {
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "/get-table" + "/*", TABLE_REQUEST_CODE);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "/get-row" + "/*", ROW_REQUEST_CODE);
    sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "/search" + "/*", TABLE_SEARCH_REQUEST_CODE);
}
```

And the uri being passed is contructed in the following code:

```
    Uri.Builder uriBuilder = DBContentProvider.CONTENT_URI.buildUpon();

    switch(id){
    case LOADER_GET_TABLE_ID :
        uriBuilder.appendPath("get-table");
        uriBuilder.appendPath("q");
        uriBuilder.appendQueryParameter("table", formID);
        return new CursorLoader(context, uriBuilder.build(), null, null, null, null);
    case ...
```

I debug the method and I am able to see the URI as it comes in the parameter, but it never matches.

How the uri comes:

```
content://edu.uprm.civil.db/get-table/q?table=150
```

If you need any more info please let me know, it's been a headache for me...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Modify the rules for your `UriMatcher` and remove the starting `/` from the path parameter:

```
sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "get-table" + "/*", TABLE_REQUEST_CODE);
sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "get-row" + "/*", ROW_REQUEST_CODE);
sURIMatcher.addURI(AUTHORITY, "search" + "/*", TABLE_SEARCH_REQUEST_CODE);
```