# UriMatcher won't correctly match all of my URIs

Tags: android, uri, android-contentprovider

I'm sorry that there's yet another UriMatcher thread, but I simply can't wrap my head around why it isn't working.

I've got the following code for my UriMatcher:

```
private static final int AGENDA = 200;
private static final int AGENDA_ID = 201;
private static final int AGENDA_AFTER = 202;
private static final int AGENDA_BEFORE = 203;
private static final int AGENDA_DATE_FILTERED = 204;

public static UriMatcher buildUriMatcher() {
    final UriMatcher matcher = new UriMatcher(UriMatcher.NO_MATCH);
    final String authority = AppContract.CONTENT_AUTHORITY;

    // Checks for a collection of items:
    // Ex: content://com.example.app/agenda
    matcher.addURI(authority, AppContract.PATH_AGENDA, AGENDA);
    // Checks for a single item
    // Ex: content://com.example.app/agenda/1
    matcher.addURI(authority, AppContract.PATH_AGENDA + "/#", AGENDA_ID);
    // Checks for a collection of items
    // Ex: content://com.example.app/agenda/after?date=2014-08-09%2014%3A17%3A51
    matcher.addURI(authority, AppContract.PATH_AGENDA + "/" + AppContract.AgendaEntry.AGENDA_AFTER + "/*", AGENDA_AFTER);
    // Checks for a collection of items
    // Ex: content://com.example.app/agenda/before?date=2014-08-09%2014%3A17%3A51
    matcher.addURI(authority, AppContract.PATH_AGENDA + "/" + AppContract.AgendaEntry.AGENDA_BEFORE + "/*", AGENDA_BEFORE);
    // Check for a collection of items
    // Ex: content://com.example.app/agenda?limit=before&date=2014-08-09%2014%3A35%3A47
    matcher.addURI(authority, AppContract.PATH_AGENDA + "/*/*", AGENDA_DATE_FILTERED);

    return matcher;
}
```

And this is my Contract class:

```
public class AppContract {

    public static final String CONTENT_AUTHORITY = "com.example.app";

    public static final Uri BASE_CONTENT_URI = Uri.parse("content://" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY);

    public static final String PATH_AGENDA = "agenda";


    /* Inner class that defines the table contents of the location table */
    public static final class AgendaEntry implements BaseColumns {

        public static final Uri CONTENT_URI =
                BASE_CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(PATH_AGENDA).build();

        public static final String CONTENT_TYPE =
                "vnd.android.cursor.dir/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_AGENDA;
        public static final String CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE =
                "vnd.android.cursor.item/" + CONTENT_AUTHORITY + "/" + PATH_AGENDA;

        // Used in the Uri to select events
        public static final String AGENDA_BEFORE = "before";
        public static final String AGENDA_AFTER = "after";
        public static final String LIMIT = "limit";

        // Table name
        public static final String TABLE_NAME = "agenda";

        // Table columns
        public static final String COLUMN_APP_ID = "app_id";
        public static final String COLUMN_DATE = "date";
        public static final String COLUMN_TITLE = "title";
        public static final String COLUMN_SMALL_IMAGE_URL = "small_image_url";
        public static final String COLUMN_LARGE_IMAGE_URL = "large_image_url";
        public static final String COLUMN_HEADLINE = "headline";
        public static final String COLUMN_MESSAGE = "message";
        public static final String COLUMN_LAST_UPDATE = "last_update";

        public static Uri buildAgendaUri(long id) {
            return ContentUris.withAppendedId(CONTENT_URI, id);
        }

        public static Uri buildAgendaWithStartDate(String startDate) {
            return CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(AGENDA_AFTER).appendQueryParameter(COLUMN_DATE, startDate).build();
        }

        public static Uri buildAgendaWithEndDate(String endDate) {
            return CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendPath(AGENDA_BEFORE).appendQueryParameter(COLUMN_DATE, endDate).build();
        }

        public static Uri buildAgendaWithDateLimit(String limit, String date) {
            return CONTENT_URI.buildUpon().appendQueryParameter(LIMIT, limit).appendQueryParameter(COLUMN_DATE, date).build();
        }

        public static String getLimitFromUri(Uri uri) {
            return uri.getQueryParameter(LIMIT);
        }

        public static String getDateFromUri(Uri uri) {
            return uri.getQueryParameter(COLUMN_DATE);
        }
    }
}
```

In the code piece for the UriMatcher you can see examples for each kind of Uri generated by their respective functions. Actual `AGENDA` and `AGENDA_ID` Uris are matched without any issues. However I can't get any of the other three to work. `AGENDA_AFTER`and `AGENDA_BEFORE` always get `-1` and `AGENDA_DATE_FILTERED` is always matched to `AGENDA`.

I've based a lot of this on the [Sunshine](https://github.com/udacity/Sunshine/tree/6.02-notifications) Android app from the Udacity course, in which they have one of the following Uris on which I based one of mine:

```
content://com.example.android.sunshine.app/weather/94043?date=20140809
content://com.example.app                 /agenda /after?date=2014-08-09%2014%3A17%3A51
```

Which are matched like this:

```
matcher.addURI(authority, WeatherContract.PATH_WEATHER + "/*/*", WEATHER_WITH_LOCATION_AND_DATE);
matcher.addURI(authority, AppsssContract.PATH_AGENDA   + "/*/*", AGENDA_AFTER);
```

The sunshine one matches without any issues, however mine simply doesn't. Even when I change the order and put it on top, to prevent any other Uri from matching (info gotten from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030094/problems-with-androids-urimatcher)), it still doesn't work.

So lets take this one as an example:

```
content://com.example.app/agenda/after?date=2014-08-09%2014%3A17%3A51
matcher.addURI(authority, AppContract.PATH_AGENDA + "/" + AppContract.AgendaEntry.AGENDA_AFTER + "/*", AGENDA_AFTER);
```

According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030094/problems-with-androids-urimatcher) post the Uri matcher matches per segment. So first it should match `AppContract.PATH_AGENDA` which is simply `agenda`. This is followed by a `/` to seperate the path. After this we get `AppContract.AgendaEntry.AGENDA_AFTER` which is simply `after`. This should also match. Last but not least we have a `/*` which should match to the question mark and the date query. But somehow it can't match and I'm really wondering what exactly I'm missing.

I also can't figure out why this matcher should match the Uri:

```
matcher.addURI(authority, AppContract.PATH_AGENDA, AGENDA);
content://com.example.app/agenda?limit=before&date=2014-08-09%2014%3A35%3A47
```

It seems as if the `?` isn't correctly seen as a segment, even though in the Sunshine example above it does seem to recognize it as one. That's the only reason I can think of why it does match this Uri and not the Uris for `AGENDA_BEFORE` and `AGENDA_AFTER`

I went through a bunch of similar questions, for example [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23718100/urimatcher-doesnt-match-correctly) (shouldn't be an issue due to the variables I use) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10256773/uri-matching-on-content-provider-not-matching-correctly) (no `/`in the variables) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16879548/urimatcher-not-recognizing-pattern) which lead me to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5030094/problems-with-androids-urimatcher) question which I still found the most informative. But I still can't seem to figure it out. Though I guess it'll turn out to be something very simple.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to separate your **query** from your **path** with a "/".

**Incorrect:** `content://com.example.app/agenda/after?date=2014-08-09%2014%3A17%3A51`

**Correct** `content://com.example.app/agenda/after/date=2014-08-09%2014%3A17%3A51`

You also **shouldn't use the wildcard ( * ) to create a match for your queries**.

**Incorrect:** `matcher.addURI(authority, AppContract.PATH_AGENDA + "/" + AppContract.AgendaEntry.AGENDA_AFTER + "/*", AGENDA_AFTER);`

**Correct:** `matcher.addURI(authority, AppContract.PATH_AGENDA + "/" + AppContract.AgendaEntry.AGENDA_AFTER, AGENDA_AFTER);`

I hope it helps.